# MVC 5 Client Side Unobtrusive Validation not stopping postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm taking over an MVC 5 project that I'm trying to get Client Side validation to work. Someone had stripped out all of the bundling and was referencing the CSS and JS manually. I've since added back the bundling and think I have that all correct now.

However, once I setup client side validation based on the articles I've found, I can't get it to stop the postback. From everything I've found about setting up client-side validation, I have it setup correctly but I must be missing something.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
    <div>....main code...</div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")        
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vendorscripts")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Index.cshtml (code at bottom of page). It's the RequestForm that I'm submitting and trying to get it to stop postback if data is missing.

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    <script type="text/javascript">

        //turn on datepicker
        $(function () {
            $(".date-picker").datepicker({ format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        });


        $("#RequestForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#divLoading").show();

            var url = $("#RequestForm").attr("action");
            var data = $("#RequestForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                    $("#RequestFormPanel").hide();

                    $("#resultsPanel").html(response);

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    if (xhr.status == 500) {
                        alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error.');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                }
            })

        });

    </script>
}
```

Bundle.config

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vendorscripts").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui.js",
                  "~/Scripts/fontawesome-all.min.js"));
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I noticed `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` bundle initialization is placed above jQuery bundle, could you check if you getting JS errors from browser's console?

Comment: When I initially looked I did have an error about not finding the Validation.js but I moved the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") back to the _Layout.cshtml just under the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"). I then tested again and the clientside errors went away but it's still doing a postback when it should be stopping on the client due to errors. The @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") is in the same location where it is put in a default creation of an MVC 5 project so I assume it's in the correct spot.